# Como fazer conexão direto na tabela?

Tags: java

Quero saber como faz para montar o `Connection` em Java para realizar a conexão direto na tabela, ou se é possível fazer isso.

Exemplo:

```
conexao = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/scrum/usuario","root","tonhaoroot");
```

Database: Scrum
tabela: usuario

O modo de declarar a conexão está correta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não, não está.

Você não se conecta diretamente à tabela e sim ao banco de dados, no caso `scrum`. Remova a parte `/usuario` da sua string de conexão.

Feito isso, "SE" o seu usuário tiver permissão de acesso à tabela, você pode mexer nela por intermédio do objeto `Connection` (fazer consultas, inserções, etc).